# In batch scripting how to extract number from a string using regex?

Tags: regex, batch-file

I tried this! It will output thebentire string!. I need to extract just the number part (123):

```
C:\Documents and Settings\kamats\Desktop>echo 123sunil | findstr "\d*"

123sunil

C:\Documents and Settings\kamats\Desktop>
```

Comment: `set "str=123sunil" & set /A "number=str"`

Comment: Cool , that works. I'm iterating through a filenames(which start with digits), I need to extract the numbers and compare it with a given number.

Comment: `find` and `findstr` always return the entire line in case it matches...

Comment: use [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044): `for /f %%a in ('echo 123sunil ^| call jrepl "\D*(\d+)\D*" "$1"') do set number=%%a`